# The site header is bouncing in Microsoft Edge on scroll

Tags: bug, design, microsoft-edge

The top header is bouncing when I am scrolling down. It is fine in Firefox and Chrome; this is happening only on Microsoft Edge browser.

It is a little bit annoying to see it bouncing.

[image]

Comment: Solution: Check the _"Disable top bar stickiness"_ option in your settings. ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus that worked but now header is scrolling away . I want it to be there and not to bounce

Comment: This is a known problem with IE and Edge. Elements fixed using `Position:fixed;` tend to bounce when scrolling if smooth scrolling is enabled. I'd complain to Microsoft about it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27966735/7296893) for an example. You can disable smooth scrolling on your side to avoid the problem. Hacky workarounds are available.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not getting this problem, not even in IE, and I have smooth scrolling disabled because it gives me motion sickness :-)

Comment: The problem still exists even after disabling smooth scroll

Comment: And I keep hearing that the days of IE6 is over ...